# Retrieving the date in SQL Server; CURRENT_TIMESTAMP vs GetDate()

Tags: sql-server, datetime, getdate

Using SQL Server, which is the fastest or best practice method to use for date retrieval? Is there a difference between `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `GetDate()`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is standard ANSI SQL, and so is theoretically one tiny little island of 'don't need to change' amongst your thousands of SQL Server-specific lines of SQL if you ever need to move databases....

Comment: You can also use `{fn now()}` equivalently if you want to go *really* old-school.

Answer (score 33):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is part of the ANSI SQL spec. `GETDATE()` is a SQL Server-specific function inherited from the original Sybase code on which SQL Server is based.

They do exactly the same thing, though.

Answer (score 11):

My vote is for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for 'portability' reasons i.e. why be SQL Server -specific when there is a direct SQL-92 equivalent?

PS why was it not named `getdatetime()`? Now that SQL Server 2008 has a `DATE` and `TIME` data type, we can hope to get support for SQL-92's `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_TIME`, at which point `getdate()` could be potentially even more confusing.

Answer (score 8):

Books Online tells us that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` "is equivalent to `GETDATE()`".