# SQL Server equivalent of MySQL's NOW()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a MySQL guy working on a SQL Server project, trying to get a datetime field to show the current time.  In MySQL I'd use NOW() but it isn't accepting that.

```
INSERT INTO timelog (datetime_filed) VALUES (NOW())
```

Answer (score 255, accepted):

`getdate()` or `getutcdate()`.

Answer (score 93):

```
getdate()
```

is the direct equivalent, *but you should always use UTC datetimes*

```
getutcdate()
```

whether your app operates across timezones or not - otherwise you run the risk of screwing up date math at the spring/fall transitions

Comment: Are there any places where the time zone change straddles a date change? Here in PST, the time zone change always happens several hours past midnight.

Answer (score 35):

[`SYSDATETIME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) and [`SYSUTCDATETIME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630387.aspx)

are the [DateTime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) equivalents of

[`GetDate()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) and [`GetUTCDate()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx)

which return a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

[DateTime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) is now the preferred method for storing the date and time in SQL Server 2008+. See the following [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime).

Answer (score 29):

You can also use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, if you feel like being more ANSI compliant (though if you're porting code between database vendors, that'll be the least of your worries). It's exactly the same as `GetDate()` under the covers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186572/retriving-date-in-sql-server-currenttimestamp-vs-getdate) for more on that).

There's no ANSI equivalent for `GetUTCDate()`, however, which is probably the one you should be using if your app operates in more than a single time zone ...

Comment: I like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` because it works in MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle... As you said, it's the least of our worries but it always helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the functions that you can use in SQL Server instead of NOW()

**1. SYSDATETIME()
2. GETDATE ()
3. GETUTCDATE()
4. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

These functions give almost the exact Date and Time while  SYSDATETIME gives a more precise time in milliseconds.

Query:
SELECT SYSDATETIME()

Output:
2022-12-21 19:38:49.4181976

Query:
SELECT GETDATE () | GETUTCDATE() | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Output:
2022-12-21 19:38:49.413