# difference between DateTime and DateTime2

Tags: .net, dbtype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server datetime2 vs datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime)

What is the difference between `DbType.DateTime` and `DbType.DateTime2` in .NET?

If I am using `DbType.Date` and I want to change to a DateTime type should I use `DateTime` or `DateTime2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime

Comment: I have clearly referred to the DbType class found in .NET.  I am using an MDB database so it has nothing to do with SQL Server.  This question should not be closed!

Comment: To those who upvoted my comment: please vote to reopen this question.

Answer (score 10):

`DbType.DateTime` and `DbType.DateTime2` both map to the .NET type `System.DateTime`.  If you need to have additional precision and dates that go back before 1753, then use `DateTime2`; otherwise `DateTime` will suffice.

This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) explains it pretty well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

DbType.DateTime2 and DbType.DateTime mirror exactly the types found in SQL Server as stated by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime).

When I do SQL Server work, I don't usually need that extra resolution, nor do I go back to 1753, so in .NET I tend to use System.DateTime for this and not either one.  If you need to go way back in time or need mad precision, use DbType.DateTime2 paired with a SQL Server type of DateTime2.

So in short, if you're programming using Access, you probably shouldn't be using either one.

Comment: Why shouldn't I be using either one if I am using Access?