# How to fix 'System.Data.Entity.Database.CurrentTransaction' error message in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I create a database in sqlserver2017 and tried to use entity framework6 to connect the database. it's connected and I've no any errors when compiling, but I'm having some error messages like : Database.CurrentTransaction at runtime when want to create a record in the database.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

```
/*inside the Controller*/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddStudent()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddStudent(Student new_stud)
        {                        
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                BLStudent bls = new BLStudent();
                if(bls.Add(new_stud))
                {
                    ViewBag.message = "It's recorded.";
                    ViewBag.color = "aqua";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.message = "It's not recorded.";
                    ViewBag.color = "red";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.message = "PLS enter the information correctly.";
                ViewBag.color = "red";
            }

            return View();
        }
```

```
/*inside the BLStudent Class*/

        UniversityEntities db = new UniversityEntities();

        public bool Add(Student new_stud)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Students.Add(new_stud);
                return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return false;
            }
        }
```

> Cath Exceptions :
>
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

Inner Exceptions:

> 1 - UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> 2 - SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.

how can fix this?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand nor see the full exception message.

Comment: can you also give how you define your EF db context ?

Comment: how can I see the full exception message?

Comment: it should popup on Visual Studio during debug. Make sure you enable showing of all exceptions 
(Debug-> Windows -> Exception settings ... and then check the "Common language runtime exceptions" fully)

Comment: (because CurrentTransaction does not look like an error message)

Comment: @Pac0 , I took the exceptions, and now?

Comment: If you look at the most inner exception, the problem seems to be caused by a DateTime data type issue. You should look where you have a DateTime (obsolete data type, basically) in your SQLServer DB, and change it to DateTime2 –

Comment: very very very tnx man

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the full error message

> " SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime
>   data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been
>   terminated."

It seems you have a type conversion issue in your database.

I recommend changing DateTime columns to DateTime2 in your database.

Apparently, you use DateTime type in your schema, which is not recommended, and has  conversion issues (probably for the default value in C# which is year 0001 etc.., that cannot be converted to a DateTime)

Comment: how can I send datetime to sql instead of datetime2?

Comment: @IMPERSIA some links to check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498817/difference-between-datetime-and-datetime2

Comment: Basically, remember that in C#, the default value for a `DateTime` is something like '0001-01-01 00:00:00' (like the ddefault value for an `int` is 0). This value is not possible for SQL Server `datetime` (values start at year ~1753). So ensure you have proper dates in the valid range of SQLServer, and it should work. I believe it's some kind of school assignment, using outdated exercices? Keep in mind that I don't see any good reason to use SQL datetime anymore since 2008, instead of datetime2, apart from working on a legacy database.