# How to print GETDATE() in SQL Server with milliseconds in time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, getdate

I want to print [GETDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server 2008, I need the time with milliseconds (this is for debugging purpose - to find sp's execution time )

I find this Difference

- `SELECT GETDATE()` returns **2011-03-15 18:43:44.100**
- `print GETDATE()` returns **Mar 15 2011  6:44PM**

I think SQL Server automatically typecast in print functionality.

I need to print the date like this `2011-03-15 18:43:44.100`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 133):

First, you should probably use `SYSDATETIME()` if you're looking for more precision.

To format your data with milliseconds, try `CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121)`.

For other formats, check out the [MSDN page on `CAST` and `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Print CAST(GETDATE() as Datetime2(7)) This is too works, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: PRINT CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS NVARCHAR(200)) works like a charm

Answer (score 61):

```
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113)
```

**UPDATE**

```
PRINT (CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121))
```

Answer (score 53):

If your SQL Server version supports the function FORMAT you could do it like this:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')
```

Answer (score 17):

these 2 are the same:

```
Print CAST(GETDATE() as Datetime2 (3) )
PRINT (CONVERT( VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 121))
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

better than [datetime is datetime2(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12364243/1501497)

[image]

```
declare @dt datetime2(3)=sysdatetime()
print @dt
Print CAST(sysdatetime() as Datetime2(3) )
print sysdatetime()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to `new Date().getTime()` in JavaScript :

Use the below statement to get the time in seconds.

```
SELECT  cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-09 16:22:17.897' ) as bigint)
```

Use the below statement to get the time in milliseconds.

```
SELECT  cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-09 16:22:17.897' ) as bigint)  * 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Following

```
DECLARE @formatted_datetime char(23)
SET @formatted_datetime = CONVERT(char(23), GETDATE(), 121)
print @formatted_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with return format yyyy-mm-hh hh:mi:ss.sss

```
create function fn_retornaFecha (@i_fecha datetime)
returns varchar(23)
as
begin
declare 
@w_fecha varchar(23),
@w_anio  varchar(4),
@w_mes   varchar(2),
@w_dia   varchar(2),
@w_hh    varchar(2),
@w_nn    varchar(2),
@w_ss    varchar(2),
@w_sss   varchar(3)

select @w_fecha = null

if ltrim(rtrim(@i_fecha)) is not null 
begin
   select
   @w_anio = replicate('0',4-char_length( convert(varchar(4), year(@i_fecha)) )) + convert(varchar(4), year(@i_fecha)),
   @w_mes  = replicate('0',2-char_length( convert(varchar(2),month(@i_fecha)) )) + convert(varchar(2),month(@i_fecha)),
   @w_dia  = replicate('0',2-char_length( convert(varchar(2),  day(@i_fecha)) )) + convert(varchar(2),  day(@i_fecha))  ,
   @w_hh   = replicate('0',2-char_length( convert(varchar(2),datepart( hh, @i_fecha ) ) )) + convert(varchar(2),datepart( hh, @i_fecha ) ),
   @w_nn   = replicate('0',2-char_length( convert(varchar(2),datepart( mi, @i_fecha ) ) )) + convert(varchar(2),datepart( mi, @i_fecha ) ),
   @w_ss   = replicate('0',2-char_length( convert(varchar(2),datepart( ss, @i_fecha ) ) )) + convert(varchar(2),datepart( ss, @i_fecha ) ),
   @w_sss  = convert(varchar(3),datepart( ms, @i_fecha ) ) + replicate('0',3-DATALENGTH( convert(varchar(3),datepart( ms, @i_fecha ) )  ))


   select @w_fecha = @w_anio + '-' + @w_mes + '-' + @w_dia + ' ' + @w_hh + ':' + @w_nn + ':' + @w_ss + '.' + @w_sss
end

return @w_fecha

end
go
```

Example

```
select fn_retornaFecha(getdate())
```

and the result is: 2016-12-21 10:12:50.123