# Strange datetime behavior in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

```
 declare @data datetime
 set @data = '2011-01-01 23:59:59:999'
 select @data
```

result is:

```
 2011-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Second example:

```
 declare @data datetime
 set @data = '2011-01-01 23:59:59:999'
 select 1 where @data >= '2011-01-02 00:00:00:000'
```

result

```
 1
```

My question is why and how to make it correct?

## edit

problem is in sql server 2008

Comment: What programming language? What database system?

Comment: what do you wanne do? make a check if the date is bigger than '2011-01-02 00:00:00:000' and return 1 if so?

Comment: If you don't see any problem, don't post any comment..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a  precision problem. .999 is rounded up to .000.

.997 is as close to the next day as you can get.

```
declare @data datetime
set @data = '2011-01-01T23:59:59.997'
select @data
```

Have a look here at the section about "Rounding of datetime Fractional Second Precision"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use [datetime2(3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) if you want a precision down to the millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use more precise format - datetime2 (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:XXXXXXX)

```
 declare @data datetime2
 set @data = '2011-01-01 23:59:59:999'
 select 1 where @data >= '2011-01-02 00:00:00:000'
```

Comment: I don't know datetime2. Thx, it is very helpful