# How to save Date and Time with my other data in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I am working on an inventory software in which I am placing order in my order panel, every thing is working absolutely fine, let me show you my database image:

[image]

and the code I used to enter data in DB is :

```
string sql = "";

int ProductQuantity = 0;
string ProductCode = "";
int ProductPrice = 0;
int totalPrice = 0;
string customerName;


for (int i = 0; i < lvProductInfo.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ProductCode = Convert.ToString(lvProductInfo.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
    ProductQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(lvProductInfo.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
    ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt32(lvProductInfo.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
    totalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(lvProductInfo.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
    customerName = lvProductInfo.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text;
    sql = "";
    sql = "INSERT INTO PurchaseLog (ProductCode,ProductQuantity,ProductPrice,TotalPrice,CustomerName)"
        + " VALUES ('" + ProductCode + "','" + ProductQuantity + "','" + ProductPrice + "','" + totalPrice + "','" + customerName + "')";

    clsConnection clsCn = new clsConnection();
    SqlConnection cn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    clsCn.fnc_ConnectToDB(ref cn);

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Now I want to add date and time also with all these data in my DB.

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) detected

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy where it's ?

Comment: Use `SqlParameters` to pass inserted values instead of concatenating strings which you get from UI

Comment: @psnLoverCSharp Take a look http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: ok thanks, now can you guys let me know how can i date date and time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `DateTime` variable

```
DateTime dateTime;
```

If You want to insert Current Date & Time  of your system(or server) then insert like that

```
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@DateTime",dateTime.Now);
```

OR If You want to insert mannuly (use `DateTimePicker` control) then insert as

```
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@DateTime",dateTimePicker1.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new column in your database of type `Datetime` and add the date to your insert statement, passing a date such as `DateTime.Now` in case you want to add the server date.

Be careful, you are risking SQL Injection attack you your way of creating the insert statement. You should, at least, change you code to use SqlParameters ([example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/working-with-sqlparameter-class-in-ado-net/))

Comment: i know about adding column in my DB sir, but the point i am confused on how can i pick date and time and pass it to the DB

Comment: DateTime.Now gives you the current date time. You can append that to your insert statement, like you do to the rest of the fields. But you should change that to SqlParameters for security reasons...

Comment: It's better to use SQL type datetime2. here is a relevant post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime