# equivalent of PostgreSQL type "timestamp without time zone" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

what is the type equivalent of postgresql "timestamp without time zone" in SQL Server?

would it be ok to use DateTime?

Answer (score 13):

For new development you can use the [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) data type, not the "plain" `datetime`. It stores a timestamp with no time zone, and lets you specify the precision that you need for your system.

To get the precision of 1 microsecond, which is the equivalent of [`timestamp without time zone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) in PostgreSQL, you need to specify precision of 6 fractional digits, i.e.

```
datetime2(6)
```

[See this answer for details on why Microsoft recommends using `datetime2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1334143/335858).

Comment: thanks, but is this the type to use to translate from PostgreSQL type "timestamp without time zone"?

Comment: @user441365 You need `datetime2(6)` to match PostgreSQL's precision.