# Force DateTime in Entity Framework Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I am creating a database with entity framework migrations and I would like all DateTime fields to be created as DateTime and not the default DateTime2.  I don't need the precision of DateTeim2 and I don't want the hassle of having to assign a value to every datetime field even if I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime), the MSDN documentation recommends using `datetime2`. There is no further 'hassle' using it. However, if you absolutely must have the column as a `datetime` type, then add this attribute to your property:

```
[Column(DbType="datetime")]
public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

If you are now comfortable sticking with `datetime2` and do not want to have to assign a value to the column, then make it `nullable`. For example if your property looks like this:

```
public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
```

Then change it to this:

```
public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is `Date` a new data type in the `.NET`?

Comment: Oops, well spotted. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Just set proper attribute. To map it to nullabe filed use property declaration as:

```
[Column(DbType="datetime NULL")]
public DateTime? YourDateTimeProp {get; set;}
```

Check the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype.aspx) for more information.