# Cannot convert System.String to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, string, datetime

I have problem with asp.net editing result of select from database. Everything is okay so far, i can dispay result of my select. But if i try edit one row i get InvalidOperationException. 
Cannot convert Datum_doručení from System.String to System.DateTime.
If i remove DateTime row from asp.net file it work again fine..

EDIT:

> just end up with debugging, in sql my field "Datum_doručení" have
>   value "2015-04-30 00:00:00.0000000", same as result of select in
>   asp.net. But if i try edit it, value of "Datum_doručeni" is "1.1.0001
>   0:00:00" and it will overflow because range. Why this is happening ?

EDIT2: I fix it with kind of hack solution. Using just string. But still i don't know why datetime does not work.

> ```
> public DateTime Datum_doručení { get; set; }
> changed to
> public string Datum_D { get; set; }
> ----
> s.Datum_doručení = reader.GetDateTime(4);
> changed to
> s.Datum_D = reader.GetDateTime(4).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> command.Parameters.Add("@Datum_doručení", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = zásilka.Datum_doručení;
> to
> command.Parameters.Add("@Datum_doručení", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(zásilka.Datum_D);
> ```

My class:

```
public class Zásilka
{

    public int zásilka_id { get; set; }
    public decimal objednavka_id { get; set; }
    public decimal zakaznik_id { get; set; }
    public decimal zaměstnanec_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datum_doručení { get; set; }
    public string Stav { get; set; }
    public decimal Váha { get; set; }

}
```

ClassTable:

```
public class ZásilkaTable
{


    private string selectAllDelivery = "select * from zásilka";
    private string editDelivery = "UPDATE zásilka SET objednavka_id=@objednavka_id, zakaznik_id=@zakaznik_id, zaměstnanec_id=@zaměstnanec_id, Datum_doručení=@Datum_doručení, Stav=@Stav, Váha=@Váha WHERE zásilka_id=@zásilka_id";


    public Collection<ORM.Zásilka> SelectAllDelivery()
    {
        Collection<ORM.Zásilka> delivery = null;
        Database db = new Database();
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            db.Connect();

            SqlCommand command = db.CreateCommand(selectAllDelivery);
            reader = db.Select(command);

            delivery = new Collection<Zásilka>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Zásilka s = new Zásilka();

                s.zásilka_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                s.objednavka_id = reader.GetDecimal(1);
                s.zakaznik_id = reader.GetDecimal(2);
                s.zaměstnanec_id = reader.GetDecimal(3);
                s.Datum_doručení = reader.GetDateTime(4);
                s.Stav = reader.GetString(5);
                s.Váha = reader.GetDecimal(6);


                delivery.Add(s);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            db.Close();
        }
        return delivery;
    }


    public string Update(Zásilka zásilka)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = db.CreateCommand(editDelivery);

            command.Parameters.Add("@zásilka_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = zásilka.zásilka_id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@objednavka_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = zásilka.objednavka_id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@zakaznik_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = zásilka.zakaznik_id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@zaměstnanec_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = zásilka.zaměstnanec_id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Datum_doručení", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = zásilka.Datum_doručení;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Stav", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = zásilka.Stav;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Váha", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = zásilka.Váha;
            db.Connect();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Close();
        }


        return "OK";
    }




}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Zásilka.aspx.cs" Inherits="dais.Zásilka" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">




    <center>
        <h1>Seznam zásilek</h1>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceadAS" DataKeyNames="zásilka_id">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="zásilka_id" HeaderText="zásilka_id" SortExpression="zásilka_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="objednavka_id" HeaderText="objednavka_id" SortExpression="objednavka_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="zakaznik_id" HeaderText="zakaznik_id" SortExpression="zakaznik_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="zaměstnanec_id" HeaderText="zaměstnanec_id" SortExpression="zaměstnanec_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Datum_doručení" HeaderText="Datum_doručení" SortExpression="Datum_doručení" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stav" HeaderText="Stav" SortExpression="Stav" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Váha" HeaderText="Váha" SortExpression="Váha" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceadAS" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="dais.ORM.Zásilka" SelectMethod="SelectAllDelivery" TypeName="dais.ORM.ZásilkaTable" UpdateMethod="Update"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

    </center>



</asp:Content>
```

And in sql database:

```
CREATE TABLE [zásilka]
(
 [zásilka_id] INT NOT NULL,
 [objednavka_id] Decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 [zakaznik_id] Decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 [zaměstnanec_id] Decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
 [Datum_doručení] Datetime NOT NULL,
 [Stav] Varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 [Váha] Decimal(10,0) NOT NULL
)
go
```

Exact error

```
Podrobnosti o výjimce: System.InvalidOperationException: Nelze převést hodnotu parametru Datum_doručení z System.String na System.DateTime.

Zdrojová chyba:

Při provádění aktuálního webového požadavku byla vyvolána neošetřená výjimka. Informace týkající se původu a umístění výjimky lze zjistit pomocí níže uvedeného trasování zásobníku výjimek.

Trasování zásobníku:


[InvalidOperationException: Nelze převést hodnotu parametru Datum_doručení z System.String na System.DateTime.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ConvertType(Object value, Type type, String paramName, ParsingCulture parsingCulture) +416
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.BuildObjectValue(Object value, Type destinationType, String paramName, ParsingCulture parsingCulture) +166
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.BuildDataObject(Type dataObjectType, IDictionary inputParameters) +210
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +1276
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +87
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1210
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +738
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +89
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9664586
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: try Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetString(4));

Comment: Use a `DateTime2(7)` or other in SQL instead of `Datetime`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime

Comment: a try convert but its not in string so it throw me an convert exception, also try DateTime2 but still same problem

Comment: What text are you entering into the field that gives the error?

Comment: just end up with debugging, in sql my field "Datum_doručení" have value "2015-04-30 00:00:00.0000000", same as result of select in asp.net. But if i try edit it, value of "Datum_doručeni" is "1.1.0001 0:00:00" and it will overflow because range is wrong obviously. But why this is happening ? I solved same thing with same way and it work great.

Answer (score 0):

May be your datetime field is null in database.
use declaration in class: `Nullable<DateTime> Datum_doručení ;`

Comment: still same problem, anyway why you think it can be null ? In sql i have  [Datum_doručení] Datetime NOT NULL, and even in query result there is not any null field