# SaveChangesAsync Error: Conversion of DateTime2 to DateTime Out-Of-Range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, async-await

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times on StackOverflow, but none of the answers seem to fit my situation, or they just tell them to allow NULL fields in their DateTime (which I don't want to do).

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<int> CreateJobAsync(JobViewModel jvm)
    {
        Job j = new Job();
        j.Name = jvm.Name;
        j.UserId = jvm.UserId;
        j.ClassDefinition = jvm.ClassDefinition;
        j.DaysToRun = jvm.DaysToRun;
        j.ToEmail = jvm.ToEmail;
        j.Active = true;
        j.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        j.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

        context.Jobs.Add(j);
        var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return result;
    }
```

All my fields in the `Job` class are `DateTime` as are the object in the database.  The date values are not `NULL`.  When I run **Sql Profiler**, it doesn't even show that a database call was made.

The Error occurs on the `await` call and it is:

> conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

This seems like a fairly easy example and I do need these values to be `not null`.   Any other ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be other field(s) in `Job` that are of type `DateTime` that are **not being set** in your code.  This unset property will default to `DateTime.MinValue` which is 1-Jan-0001.  The SQL type DATETIME only supports dates with a year greater than 1752.  Hence, the reason for your exception.

The easiest solution is to change the database to use DATETIME2 and not DATETIME.  See also [DateTime2 vs DateTime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime)

Comment: Let me work on researching this.  After seeing your answer, I reviewed Job.cs and there is another class inside it.  And, THAT class has a DateTime in it.

Comment: That was it.  The class referenced inside Job had a DateTime that was defaulting to DateTime.MinValue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

DateTime is a value type in .Net and will never be null.

Now, being said that, the default value for DateTime is `DateTime.MinValue` in `C#` which equals to `01/01/0001`, and all DateTime fields get this value by default, unless otherwise specified! But, this date is out of `SQLServer` date ranges, for which minimum date is `1/1/1753`. Probably that's why you are getting this exception.

One way to make your code usable will be to use [SqlDateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: In my code, I am setting the values to DateTime.Now and I've even tried hard-coding today's date, but still get the same error.  I'm not sure why it would use use DateTime.MinValue.  The point out never getting a null value is valid so I'll try changing my database.

Comment: @L_7337 Somewhere in the code, some datetime field might be un-initialized, or ill-formatted. There are host of ways to counter this - please search SO with "conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" for multiple existing answers.