# Powerbuilder Datawindow + Datetime2 Error

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder, datawindow, datetime2, sybase-ase15

I am in the process of Converting a large application to work against SQL Server 2014. It is currently running against Sybase ASE 15.

The Problem is when I try to retrieve a value from a column that is defined as Datetime2, I get  "Error: Invalid DataWindow row/column specified at line". This line in defined in the Sybase table as Datetime and retrieves correct.

Also, there are no milliseconds data value for this column.

Any ideas of what is causing it or how to correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'datetime2' datatype in Powerbuilder.
From the Documentation:

> DateTime The date and time in a single datatype, used only for reading
>   and writing DateTime values from and to a database. ...
>
> PowerBuilder supports microseconds in the database interface for any
>   DBMS that supports microseconds.

Are you not seeing miliseconds in the datawindow?  Check to see if there is a format setting on the column which removes them from the display.  Try using a format in the datawindow column similar to "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss:ffffff" and see if the microseconds are displayed.

Comment: Did you mean Sybase doesn't have Datetime2?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The datawindow Column is defined as Datetime and that should work according to the PB Documentation. There is no value for milliseconds.

Comment: SQL Server has date, datetime, datetime2 & time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime

Comment: Matt is correct. If you need help I'm on the bench atm.