# What is the correct MSSQL datatype if we want to support milliseconds in timestamp?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

For example, in ORACLE, if we choose TIMESTAMP(3), it supports milliseconds.
For example, we could store in Oracle database, data like: 2016-11-28T14:48:15.565

For MSSQL, what should be the datatype chosen out of 
datetime, datetime2?

Comment: see this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/1334193/2975396

Answer (score 0):

you can define the data with Datetime type
The precision of DATETIME is ms and the precision of DATETIME2 is μs

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME=SYSDATETIME(),@d2 DATETIME2=SYSDATETIME()
SELECT @d AS d1,@d2 AS d2
```

output:

```
d1                      d2
----------------------- ---------------------------
2016-11-28 17:39:51.773 2016-11-28 17:39:51.7734965
```

Comment: The precision of DATETIME is 0.00333 seconds.