# DateTime comparison in LINQ not returning correct results

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have the following LINQ to query the database and retreive deleted products from a particular date.

```
 return _myDbEntities.Log
            .Where(p => p.Action.Equals("Deleted") &&
            (p.ActionDate > fromDate))
            .Select(p => new DeletedProduct()
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                ActionDate = p.ActionDate
            }).ToList();
```

However, the query is retreiving values like product.ActionDate.Value = {12/8/2016 11:41:00 AM} when the fromDate was fromDate = {12/8/2016 11:41:00 AM}

The query clearly says GREATER THAN. What is happening here?

Comment: Check the fraction of a second (or display it as timestamp). Maybe the difference is there

Comment: What type is ActionDate? Could you try (p.ActionDate.Value > fromDate)?

Comment: In the query you are using `product.ActionDate` but tit seems you need `product.ActionDate.Value`

Comment: try to see the result SQL query, in debug mode

Comment: Datetime also stores the ms, have you checked that difference? Also have you analysed the produced query?

Comment: I've recreated your code and it "works". Can you please provide a reproduction that shows your code failing? https://dotnetfiddle.net/pqXduz

Comment: I think the problem in the formatting, the server formatting maybe is Month then day then year and year client machine as day then month then year

Comment: And here's an example of the output when dealing with small fractions of a second: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ABGDjA

Comment: I tried DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(p.ActionDate, fromDate) in the query. It resulted in this exception:

{"The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart."}

Comment: @HadiHassan DateTime is a binary type, both in .NET and the database. There is no formatting involved, unless the OP used strings instead of DateTime values

Comment: @AliKareemRaja SQL date comparisons aren't broken. There's no need to look for tricks like comparing milliseconds. What are the types of `ActionDate` and `fromDate`? Are they both `datetime`? What do they contain? Please capture and post the actual query that gets executed, eg by using SQL Server Profiler or setting the log property `context.Database.Log = Console.Write;`

Comment: Also note that your query will *correctly* return values with a millisecond component. If you don't want that, use  `>= fromDate` with a value of `11:41:01`. This isn't a query problem, you are using the wrong bound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are fractions of a second to each of your properties. Most likely, your record wasn't created at an exact second, whereas any user-created time would be set as such.

Another possibility is the [difference between `datetime` and `datetime2` in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` type stores time at much higher precision than seconds. They could be differing at millisecond or even tick (100 nanoseconds) level.

If you want to compare on a higher level, try this:

```
(p.ActionDate.Ticks / 10000000) > (fromDate.Ticks / 10000000)
```

Where `10000000` is the number of ticks in a second. Since the `/`is an integer division that does truncate the fraction, you turn ticks into full seconds.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like you are using entity framework. The comparison above will possibly not work there. The solution is to run your original query against the database, do a `ToList` and then filter the results again in a `LINQ2Objects` query using the logic above.

Comment: You do **not** want to pull in a list of everything to do additional filtering on it in memory. Depending on the size of the project, this could generate a LOT of extra data being returned from the database that then needs to be parsed into C# objects. Utilize the tools that you have (SQL Server), and let that do the filtering for you.

Comment: @krillgar: You don't pull a list of everything. You pull the original query result, which already does the comparison. The second filter is to filter the few results where the values are differing only on sub-second level.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. If the OP doesn't have the ability to change the database to a `datetime2` column, this would work. However, if they can make that change, you wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: @krillgar: Correct, _if_ they can make the change. That is not always possible or the DB could change later. If you run a second filter query on a general basis, you are safe in any possible scenario and you lose nothing.

Comment: In most cases, yeah. I work in an enterprise environment, and just spent most of the year working on a request system. I've been in the mindset of several thousand requests that were huge objects being created every day, so pulling several hundred of those in for every query would have created a big lag.

Comment: However, if this is a smaller project where under 100 smaller object would be created, then this would be no problem.