# PDO dblib date format different than tsql

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, centos, freetds

I've got a CentOS 7 machine running PHP with webtatic PHP 5.6 and the php56w-mssql package installed. My application is in the Laravel framework connecting to an MSSQL 2012 database.

I've modified the locales.conf file so that all it has in it is

```
[default]
    date format = %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.000
```

And when running a query from within tsql I get back the properly formatted date including the zeros for milliseconds at the end. However, when running the query either in PHP interactive mode, or through artisan tinker, I get a date format without the trailing milliseconds.

I have an Ubuntu machine running the exact same configuration, and tsql, PHP, and artisan tinker all give me back the properly formatted date, it's just this CentOS machine that's an issue.

My `freetds.conf` sets tds version 7.4 for it's global setting and has the host entry (which is what is currently configured in Laravel) that is

```
[fancy]
    host = 10.0.0.12
    port = 1433
    database = fancy
    tds version = 7.4
    client charset = UTF-8
```

Comment: If "it's just this CentOS machine that's an issue" then perhaps you could trade in the "sql-server" tag for a "centos" tag.

Comment: Your Freetds config has nothing to do with PHP,  and the way it talks to sql server

Comment: Tell that to dblib. Try new PDO('dblib:host=fancy;database=fancy', 'user', 'pass'); with a bad config in freetds.conf

Comment: Try tds version 8

Comment: Good for you. I have an Ubuntu 18.10 machine, and the locales.conf file appears to be completely ignored for me, even though I'm using the dblib driver.

Comment: Check this comment, I think it may solve your issue: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12364243/4458348