# Insert into Table getdate() rounds seconds in ASP.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a logs table with a `smalldatetime` column.

When I'm inserting into the table the value of `GETDATE()` the data is inserted without the seconds.

Example result: 2017-01-15 15:20:00

What am I missing?

Comment: proplem with you data type . can you use datetime instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms182418.aspx)

**smalldatetime**

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day. The time is based
>   on a 24-hour day, with seconds always zero (:00) and without
>   fractional seconds.

If you want `seconds` then use `DATETIME` datatype instead of `smalldatetime`

```
DECLARE @smalldatetime SMALLDATETIME = '1955-12-13 12:43:10',
        @datetime      DATETIME = '1955-12-13 12:43:10'

SELECT @smalldatetime as [SmallDateTime],
       @datetime as [DateTime]
```

**Result :**

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+
|    SmallDateTime    |        DateTime         |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 1955-12-13 12:43:00 | 1955-12-13 12:43:10.000 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server 2008 and above:

Use `datetime2(p)` instead of `smalldatetime` and `sysdatetime()` instead of `getdate()`.

`datetime` is 8 bytes; `1753-01-01T00:00:00.000 to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.997` (time rounded to .000, .003, .007)

`datetime2(2)` is 6 bytes; `0001-01-01T00:00:00.00 to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.99`

`datetime2(4)` is 7 bytes; `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000 to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999`

`datetime2(7)` is 8 bytes; `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000 to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999`

Note: When adding a .NET `DateTime` as a parameter, use `System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2`. `datetime2` can store any value that can be stored in the .NET DateTime type.

Learn more:

- [sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime)
- [datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)
- [datetime2 (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)