# Beside compatibility with SQL Server 2000 and 2005, is there any other issue to use datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know datetime2 is faster than datetime and also is using less storage space for the same accuracy. Do you know any other impediment to migrate my fields from datetime to datetime2 rather than compatibility with SQL Server 2000 and 2005?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a front end application against your database? Is it compatible with datetime2?

Comment: Yes,it is compatible with datetime2.

Comment: datetime2 is more precise and a wider daterange
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server

but i wouldn't change the column format if there is no explicit need

Comment: I now use `datetime2(0)` extensively to store datetimes that are useful and readable by humans (record audit timestamps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no downsides with using `datetime2` versus `datetime` as long as you use `datetime2` only or avoid conversions between these two data types.

There is a potentially [breaking change in SQL Server 2016](http://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-2016-and-azure-sql-database-v12-breaking-change/) with regards to value rounding when converting between these types that could be an issue depending on your code.