# GETDATE() Function error on TSQL with Always Encrypted Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am working with SQL Server hosted on Azure. I have a table named "ERROR" with a column named "DATETIME" with Always Encrypted feature enabled.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ERROR]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DATETIME] [datetime] ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,
    [CODE] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [MESSAGE] [varchar](500) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ERROR] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

I'm running a stored procedure to add a row in another table, but if an error is caught it add the error to this table with the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ERROR] ([DATETIME], [CODE], [MESSAGE])
VALUES (GETDATE(), @@ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE())
```

My issue is when I try to enter `GETDATE()` value into the encrypted column, I get this error

> Operand type clash: datetime is incompatible with datetime encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Aeropuerto')

Following some recommendations on the web I enabled PARAMETERIZATION FOR ALWAYS ENCRYPTED on SSMS and declared it first like this `DECLARE @RAISEDTIME DATETIME = '20181130'`. after this no error was raised and it is inserted successfully, but when assing GETDATE() as value [`DECLARE @RAISEDTIME DATETIME = GETDATE()`] I get this error:

> Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@RAISEDTIME'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '3' expects it to be (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Aeropuerto') (or weaker).

I have tried to format `GETDATE()` value with ISO8601 but the same error below is raised.

Can you recommend me a way to insert the actual datetime value with this stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried DECLARE @RAISEDTIME DATETIME = getdate() and inserting the variable?

Comment: Yes INSERT INTO [dbo].[ERROR]( [DATETIME], [CODE], [MESSAGE])
   VALUES(@RAISEDTIME, @CODE, @MESSAGE)

Comment: use that.  That little bit of indirection makes it deterministic

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Getting confused.  I thought you said it did?

Comment: Unrelated tips: there is no reason to be using DateTime any more: [prefer datetime2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server). Also, why name the `DateTime` column after the type: give it a name representing what it contains: e.g. `OccurredAt`.

Comment: @user1443098 sorry, I wanted to say that I have already tried it.

Comment: @Richardissimo thanks for your advise, I really apreciate those types of comments.

Comment: What's the point of using Always Encrypted on this date column? It's overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage [Parameterization for Always Encrypted columns](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/). You have to understand that with an AE column, the server *does not have the encryption key*, so it cannot possibly insert a value declared in a batch script. The value *must* be encrypted by the client, which has the encryption key.

With SQL Server 2017, Always Encrypted column parameterization is *possible*, see the linked article. But it works only under certain conditions. And it definitely not works in SQL Server 2016.

You'll be much better to **send the value from the client**, as with most Always Encrypted column use cases.