# Convert Datetime string to date in SQL Server

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a datetime data from C# like this

```
2019-03-20T11:25:32.0342949
```

I tried to convert it to datetime using cast and it triggers error

```
select cast('2019-03-20T11:25:32.0342949' as date)
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I guess its because of the `T` in the string.

I tried format also which of course doesn't work because its not identify it as date.

So how can I convert it properly to date. Without some substring methods to extract the date part.

Comment: Which SQL version used?

Comment: how are you passing the date to SQL from C#

Comment: Missed to mention.. SQL 2012

Comment: @peeyushsingh  as string

Comment: When sending dates from c# to SQL Server, don't send strings, send an instance of the `DateTime` struct. Then you don't have to mess around with conversion and string representations of datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only date this will work

```
select cast('2019-03-20T11:25:32.0342949' as date) As DATE
```

If you need date and time this will work

```
select cast('2019-03-20T11:25:32.0342949' as datetime2) As DATE
```

Tried in Sql 15 Its working

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`DATETIME2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) instead of [`DATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql):

```
SELECT CAST('2019-03-20T11:25:32.0342949' AS DATETIME2) -- 2019-03-20 11:25:32.0342949
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e3eb4f7275eac940a91e05c3aca3b10)

The issue is the precision of the milliseconds part of your string value. You are using seven digits on the milliseconds part which is not possible on `DATETIME`. So you can do two things:

- shorten the milliseconds part to three digits and use `DATETIME`
- use `DATETIME2` for more precision

---

> Use the `time`, `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. `time`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` provide more seconds precision. `datetimeoffset` provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.
>   **source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

There is also a comparison between `DATETIME` and `DATETIME2` on StackOverflow:
[DateTime2 vs DateTime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You have to take advantage of the CONVERT() method. For example, `SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())`, with `date` being the string you just mentioned. In your case, your `datetime` string takes up 10 letters of string, so you could also do `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)`. The 3rd parameter is the `datetime` style you want to convert to.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass datetime as string from C#, this is the correct way to pass:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE datevalue= @date";

SqlParameter dateParam = new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
dateParam .Value = dateValue;

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateParam );
// then execute the command...
```