# Insert / Update into SqlServer.Date column from EntityFramework v6

Tags: sql-server, datetime, entity-framework-6

NB: this is a Sql-server Date datatype (Not DateTime, nor DateTime2, which most answers seem to focus on).

How to insert from EF ?

I tried as below, but I am stuck on the .NET side.

```
 TB_MyTable newEntity = new TB_MyTable()
{
    col1 = "abc",
    col2  = 123

    dtCol       = DateTime.MinValue,
    dateOnlyCol = ??? What goes here, range is '0001-01-01' to '9999-12-31'
};

TB_MyTable inserted = dbCtx.TB_MyTable.Add(newEntity);
int rowsAffected = dbCtx.SaveChanges();
```

Error on .SaveChanges() is:

> {"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."}

Please don't suggest to me to use string on the Right-Hand-Side, it doesn't work :P

Comment: What is the data type of dtCol column? The error seems to suggest that it is datetime (min value 1/1/1753) and you are trying to insert year 0001 into it.

Comment: Alex !! oops you are right. I was focusing on the wrong problem. dtCol is DateTime. And setting it to DateTime.MinValue was causing the error. I changed it to DateTime.Now and it went thru . For dateOnlyCol I can use DateTime.MinValue.Date and it works. I can accept your answer if you write it as such.

Comment: Glad it helped! I have added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type of `dtCol` column?

The error seems to suggest that it is `datetime` (min value 1/1/1753) and you are trying to insert year 0001 (`DateTime.MinValue`) into it.

### Additionally

Microsoft recommends `DATETIME2` over `DATETIME`. For new projects I would suggest you use `DATETIME2`, not least for smoother .NET integration.

More details: [DateTime2 vs DateTime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server/1334193)