# "Syntax error or access violation" when inserting dates using PDO and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, timestamp

I am trying to add two simple strings and one date to a SQL Server using PDO in PHP. I'm  currently using the following code to do so:

```
$data = array(
    'Omschrijving' => 'Mijn mooie omschrijving...',
    'Toelichting' => 'Mijn leuke toelichting...'
);

# Insert data
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO memo (Datum, Omschrijving, Toelichting) VALUES (NOW(), :Omschrijving, :Toelichting)");
$STH->execute($data);
```

It works perfectly without the date, but for some reason it gives me the following error when I try to add the date:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 8180 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQLExecute[8180] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.6.9/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @chris85 No the keys doesn't need colons, but they can. Both ways works

Comment: Thanks for noticing @chris85, I've removed the tag "MySQL", it does not apply. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Have you checked, that your column names and table names are correct?

Comment: `Now()` is for mysql. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx @Rizier123 thanks I don't use the binding and have seen conflicting threads on that.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, I have checked. If I shouldn't be using NOW(), what should I use? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you didn't follow the provided link...`GETDATE()` here's another thread on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385042/sql-server-equivalent-of-mysqls-now

Comment: No way! I have used GETDATE() from the start, but I switched as I wasn't sure. Apparently I was chasing the wrong bug. Thanks a lot @chris85 for your help and patience! ;-) If you add this answer, I will approve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Now()` is a MySQL function. `GetDate()` is the sql-server's equivalent. Here's their documentation on the function, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx.

So provided code should become:

```
$data = array(
    'Omschrijving' => 'Mijn mooie omschrijving...',
    'Toelichting' => 'Mijn leuke toelichting...'
);

# Insert data
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO memo (Datum, Omschrijving, Toelichting) VALUES (GETDATE(), :Omschrijving, :Toelichting)");
$STH->execute($data);
```