# T-SQL version of MySQLs CURTIME()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to get teh current time as a unix timestamp from my MSSQL database.

In Mysql I could say something like:

```
SELECT id,
            caregiver_id,
            client_id,
            week_no,
            CURTIME() as Synch_Time
FROM dbo.Visits
```

But THERE is no CURTIME() function in T-SQL

Does anyone know of a solution?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 9):

You can use [getdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) and do some calculations described here.
http://mysql.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-convert-a-sql-server-datetime-value-to-a-unix-timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

`getdate()` is MSSQL specific, but `current_timestamp()` is more standard compliant. See similar question: [Retrieving date in sql server, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP vs GetDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186572/retriving-date-in-sql-server-current-timestamp-vs-getdate)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL2012, use can convert to specific date and time types, e.g.

```
   SELECT
           Time = CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE()),  
           Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```