# Sql query with the current date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I've got a simple query where I want to put the current date

```
var query = @"
    SELECT trainid, trainnum
    FROM trains 
    WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), trainstartdate, 104)=" + 
    " " + 
    // so that matches the '104' format
    String.Format("{0:dd.MM.YYYY}", DateTime.Now) +                          
    " " +
    "ORDER BY trainnum";
```

But when running I get the error message:

`Cannot call methods on numeric. .Net SqlClient Data Provider`

How do I specify current date the right way?
Thanks!

**Using GETDATE()**

Effect:
`The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`

**Using {0:dd.MM.yyyy}**

Effect: `none`

**Using CONVERT(varchar(20), GetDate(), 104)**

Effect: `that works!`

Thanks!

Comment: You should use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) with [SqlDbType.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) instead.

Comment: Whats wrong with my answer ? I just want to know to get better.

Comment: @dknaack look at my edit (`Using GETDATE`). In my case If I use just a plain `GetDate()` call then I have the error message. Instead result of `GETDATE()` should be converted to format '104'.

Comment: @helicera please check out my updated answer and compare the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = @"
SELECT trainid, trainnum
FROM trains 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), trainstartdate, 104)=
CONVERT(varchar(20), GetDate(), 104)
ORDER BY trainnum";
```

Comment: The two queries are not equivalent.  The first returns rows whose start date is sometime today; the second returns rows whose start date is right now (current date + time of day).

Comment: @Joe that's true. I removed the second query.

Answer (score 9):

#### Description

I would not convert to a varchar and doing string comparrisson. The performance is much better if you compare `trainstartdate` using the `>=` and `<`.

You can use the `T-SQL` `getDate()` method to get the current date.

> **getDate()** returns the current datetime with the time. `2012-02-14 14:51:08.350`
>
> **DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))** return only the current date. `2012-02-14 00:00:00.000
>
> **DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))** returns only the date of tomorow. `2012-02-15 00:00:00.000`

#### Sample

```
var query = @"
SELECT trainid, trainnum
FROM trains 
WHERE trainstartdate >=
-- today
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
AND trainstartdate < 
-- tommorow
DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY trainnum"
```

**Note:**
If you want to be ANSI compliant, **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** does the same.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - GETDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)
- [MSDN - DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)
- [MSDN - DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [Stackoverflow - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP vs GetDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186572/retriving-date-in-sql-server-current-timestamp-vs-getdate)

Comment: +1 - Also avoids the terrible stronc comparison that force a table scan in the OP query.

Comment: +1. Also, if you want to be ANSI compliant, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186572/retriving-date-in-sql-server-current-timestamp-vs-getdate

Comment: @nonnb nice! My answer is extended.

Comment: -1 this gives a different result from the OP's attempt: instead of the rows for the current date, it gives the rows who's trainstartdate is right now.

Comment: @Joe good comment! My answer is updated. The best solution is not to convert to a varchar. Using the `between` statement will give the best performance. Try it. Thank you!

Comment: @dknaack, Much better but still not quite right.  SQL Server's BETWEEN operator specifies an inclusive range, so your query will return rows with tomorrow's date.  Better and clearer to use ">= [today] AND < [tomorrow]".

Comment: @Joe, oh thats true. Even if we talking about 3 ms on `DateTime` and 100 nanoseconds on `DateTim2` it matters. My answer is updated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) is all you need...

Answer (score 2):

I think

```cs
String.Format("{0:dd.MM.YYYY}", DateTime.Now);
```

is returning the date with a dot, which makes SQL consider it as a number.

Try using

```cs
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

with a `/` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change the format pattern of YYYY to small-case letters

```
{0:dd.MM.yyyy}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that GETDATE() returns the current date and time of day, not only today's date.

If you want to return rows matching today's date, you need to extract the date part.  There are a number of ways to do this - e.g. with SQL Server 2008 you can use the `DATE` data type, but one general way that works with earlier versions of SQL Server is the following:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101) )
```

You can then use the query:

```
SELECT trainid, trainnum   
FROM trains    
WHERE trainstartdate = CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101) )
```

which will work provided you are sure that the date/time in the trains.trainstartdate column is a date only (time of day = 0).

If trainstartdate contains the start date/time, you can get all of today's trains as follows:

```
SELECT trainid, trainnum   
FROM trains    
WHERE trainstartdate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101) )
AND trainstartdate < DATEADD(dd,1, CONVERT(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101) ))
```

By doing it like this rather than converting to a string, you will take advantage of any index there may be on the trainstartdate column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. YYYY should be small letter yyyy

```
String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```