# Database agnostic way to filter entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I use Spring Data, Hibernate and Microsoft SQL Server. I have 2 entities: `Role` and `Privilege`. One role has many privileges. Privileges have `VALID_TO` column.
I want every role to have only privileges that are still valid (i.e., `VALID_TO <= GETDATE()`).

The simplest way I found to implement this is by annotating the `Privilege` entity with the Hibernate `@Where` annotation, like this:

```
// ...
@Where(clause = "VALID_TO <= GETDATE()")
class Privilege {
    // ...
}
```

But the disadvantage of this approach is that it uses Transact-SQL; it will cause additional rework in case of migration to another database.
Also, this approach makes the code dependent on Hibernate annotations.

Is there a way to filter out the privileges using pure Spring Data?

Comment: @SeanLange, good point. :) Going to delete the sql-server tag.

Comment: Unless there are a large number of privileges per role you could just filter on the in-memory instance rather than at the database layer i.e. do not expose the privileges collection and have a method `Role.getActivePrivileges();` Otherwise you could map the relationship to a view (if the data is writable them this would require the db to support updateable views )

Comment: @AlanHay, thank you for the hint! I think I'll stick with the in-memory filtering indeed. Just out of curiosity, am I correct that the second approach (with the view) still depends on a concrete database? Correct me if I'm wrong, but to create the view I still need to write the SQL query for it somewhere (using plain SQL).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jOOQ](http://jooq.org) to translate the SQL to any other dialect of your choice, either using the programmatic API (in case of which you could generate your predicate dynamically), or the [parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/), which can also be placed in between your application and the JDBC driver in the form of a [JDBC driver proxy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/). That way, you can continue to use `GETDATE()`, and depending on the target dialect, you'd be getting hte right output.

Of course, for the specific case of your question, using [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68858507/521799) may be your safest bet, because it's widely supported (including SQL Server), so just for this case you won't need any other third party.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ