# Error "ODBC data type -150 is not supported" when connecting sqlalchemy to mssql

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I keep running into an odd error when attempting to connect python sqlalchemy to a msssql server/database. I need to use sqlalchemy as it is (from what I've been told) the only way to connect pandas dataframes to mssql.

I have tried connecting sqlalchemy two different ways:

1. using full connection string:

   ```
   import sqlalchemy as sa
   import urllib.parse as ulp

   usrCnnStr = r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myVoid\MYINSTANCE;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
   usrCnnStr = ulp.quote_plus(usrCnnStr)
   usrCnnStr = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % usrCnnStr

   engine = sa.create_engine(usrCnnStr)
   connection = engine.connect()
   connection.execute("select getdate() as dt from mydb.dbo.dk_rcdtag")
   connection.close()
   ```
2. using DSN:

   ```
   import sqlalchemy as sa
   import urllib.parse as ulp

   usrDsn = 'myDb'
   params = ulp.quote_plus(usrDsn)
   engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://cryo:pass@myDb")
   conn = engine.connect()
   conn.execute('select getdate() as dt')
   conn.close()
   ```

Both methods return the same error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('ODBC data type -150 is not supported.  Cannot read column .', 'HY000') [SQL: "SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')"]
```

I am not sure how to get around this error; when I execute the "SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')" in mssql, it works fine but comes back with a data type of "sql_variant".

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Have you tried connecting directly via `pyodbc` first? What versions of Python, pyodbc, and SQL Alchemy are you using?

Comment: @FlipperPA I have tried connecting using pyodbc (it was my first choice), but pandas Dataframe.to_sql() requires a sqlalchemy connection when connecting to a mssql database.

Comment: Please test and confirm that https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/commits/ae9300cac0ec398f92d9e523273403126a709134 resolves, ASAP and get back to me at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3820/connection-fails-against-sql-server-2016

Comment: @zzzeek Tested and confirmed that issue is resolved with sqlalchemy v1.1.1 - Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upgraded to sqlalchemy 1.1 today and ran into a similar issue with connections that were working before. Bumped back to 1.0.15 and no problems. Not the best answer, more of a workaround, but it may work if you are on 1.1 and need to get rolling.

If you are unsure of your version:

```
>>import sqlalchemy
>>sqlalchemy.__version__
```

Comment: I just checked and I am using version 1.1.0; how can I go about downgrading?

Comment: Just need to uninstall sqlalchemy, for instance _pip uninstall sqlalchemy_ then you can do a _pip install_ then this URL: https://pypi.python.org/packages/18/7d/f230ac50198cfe3cdc957c3572a18dc92600047ce707b5b923c56ab92c1b/SQLAlchemy-1.0.15.tar.gz_

Comment: This resolved the issue. I was able to use pip to uninstall and then manually downloaded the 1.0.15 and used pip to install it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is most certainly a bug introduced in [Issue 3814](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3814), new in SQLAlchemy 1.1.0, where they introduce `SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` to fetch server version for the pyodbc MSSQL driver. Downgrading to 1.0.15 will make the code work again, but hopefully the SQLAlchemy devs will make the new version lookup scheme work better in a new patch release.

(There is [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3820/connection-fails-against-sql-server-2016) already reported in the SQLAlchemy issue tracker, I would add this comment there, but bitbucket can't log me in.)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, this is because you can't select non-cast functions directory, since they don't return a datatype *pyodbc* recognizes.

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME) AS dt
```

Also, your may want to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, which is ANSI standard SQL, instead of `GETDATE()`: [Retrieving date in sql server, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP vs GetDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186572/retriving-date-in-sql-server-current-timestamp-vs-getdate)

I'm not sure where your product version select is coming from, but hopefully this gets you on the right path. I'll amend the answer if we figure out more.

Comment: the select query is really only a place holder, but I ran it with the one you specified and still got the same error. 

The "select serverproperty('ProductVersion')" is coming from the tail end of the error.